# Best Practice: How to Insert into Multiple Tables Through the Business Layer and Data Layer?

Tags: class, insert

I USED to be a developer and part-time db designer, but it's been many years and I'm re-learning...

I'm building a web app and have a Person (actually "Profile") table with a number of child tables which have N:N relationships with my Person table, e.g.
  FavoriteSports
  MusicalInstruments
  ArtisticSkills

After reading through Scott Mitchell's excellent data access tutorials at www.asp.net, I want to design my app w/ well-thought-out Data Access (using Table Adapters) and Business Logic (using Classes) Layers.

Where I get hung up is in designing the Classes and Table Adapters. The "Unit of work" here is something more like a real-life object, that doesn't align directly with my table-based classes or data access objects. So I guess what I'm seeing is a need to build a class modeled not around the tables, but instead around the real-life object (my Profile+FavoriteSports+MusicalInstruments+ArtisticSkills).

What I'm really looking for is a good book or web site that describes how to do this. Specifically, how can I build a class that supports these child records (as collections?).  I think I understand the concepts - I just need some guidance on how to put it into practice.

The best answer I could ask for would point me at a book (C#, preferrably) that goes into all this in all its complexities - pretty sure I'm way past the "Beginners" books with this.

Thanks -

-Pete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately one book might not help. I recommend you go for these books to get back to understanding the two worlds of RDBMS and OO. Tables and business entities may not be a 1:1 map!

[Patterns of Enterprise Application Architecture](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321127420)

[Domain-Driven Design: Tackling Complexity in the Heart of Software](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321125215)

[.NET Domain-Driven Design with C#: Problem - Design - Solution](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470147563)

Hope that helps.

Comment: I went with a bunch of books - used - from Amazon...
- C# Class Design Handbook: Coding Effective Classes
- Programming Microsoft Visual C# 2005: The Base Class Library (Pro-Developer)
- C# Class Design Handbook 
- Design Patterns: Elements of Reusable Object-Oriented Software 

Hopefully between the four, I'll get what I was after.  Thanks for the suggestions.

-Pete

Comment: Those are excellent books, however I do not think they give you an idea about working end to end for a software. Best of luck!

Answer (score 1):

It'd be clear if you could follow what an ORM tool like [NHibernate](https://www.hibernate.org/343.html) presents.

The key thing is to think about it less in terms of tables and more about objects.

Sounds like you'd have a Person class with child collections for a class or interface of Skills:

```
public class Person
{
   public IList<Skill> Skills { get; set; }
}
```

It's a many-to-many relationship, but you might not need for a Skill to keep track of how many Persons are associated with it.